# Best way of handling string response from soap web service call in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, node-soap

Newbie question here. I am calling a making a web service call in node.js using node-soap and getting a response similar to the following:

```
{ AuthenticateResult:
   { PrimaryKeyId: '0',
     ValidateOnly: false,
     OperationResult: 'Succeeded',
     SessionId: 'abc45235435345' } }
```

What is the best way to extract the SessionId value from the response if OperationResult is 'Succeeded'? I am guessing I could do it with indexof and substring, but even to newbie like me, this doesn't sound like a nice solution.

Comment: use JSON.parse on the response to create an object from the string. then you can use the dot syntax e.g `response.OperationResult`

Comment: @Saar This is not valid JSON though.

Comment: @FelixKling you're right

Comment: if this value is returned as string you can instantiate it by calling `eval` however `eval` is considered a real bad practice as the response can be malicious/harmful code.

Comment: Thanks for replies. I did try JSON,parse but soon found out my string was not in correct JSON format. Was looking for the most elegant solution to extract the string so perhaps eval is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input is stored as a string, and is consistent (i.e. JSON without the quotes to the left of the colon), you can just use a regex to convert it into a JSON string, *then* use `JSON.parse()`.

```js
var input = "{ AuthenticateResult: {\n"
            + "PrimaryKeyId: '0',\n"
            + "ValidateOnly: false,\n"
            + "OperationResult: 'Succeeded',\n"
            + "SessionId: 'abc45235435345' } }";

// This replaces word: with "word": and ' with "
var json = input.replace(/(\w+):/g, '"$1":').replace(/'/g, '"');

// This here's the object you want
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

// Just printing out the JSON so you know it works.
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = json;
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Turns out that I made a big newbie mistake and node-soap was actually returning me an object that I could work with. Thanks for all the help and suggestions.